# Parsing comma present in text in csv file while transferring contents from csv file to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I want to transfer the contents of csv file to mysql.In my csv file there are columns that have text containing commas.

I am using below code to transfer the contents

`

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;




public class CSVLoader {


    static int  count;
    private static final 
        String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})";
    private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
    private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
    private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

    private Connection connection;
    private char seprator;

    /**
     * Public constructor to build CSVLoader object with
     * Connection details. The connection is closed on success
     * or failure.
     * @param connection
     */
    public CSVLoader(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        //Set default separator
        this.seprator = ',';
    }

    /**
     * Parse CSV file using OpenCSV library and load in 
     * given database table. 
     * @param csvFile Input CSV file
     * @param tableName Database table name to import data
     * @param truncateBeforeLoad Truncate the table before inserting 
     *          new records.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName,
            boolean truncateBeforeLoad) throws Exception {

        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        if(null == this.connection) {
            throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
        }
        try {

            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        //String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();
        String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();
        count++;
        if (null == headerRow) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    "No columns defined in given CSV file." +
                    "Please check the CSV file format.");
        }

        String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
        System.out.println(headerRow.length);
        questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks
                .length() - 1);

        String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
        query = query
                .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
        query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

        System.out.println("Query: " + query);

        String[] nextLine;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            con = this.connection;
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

            if(truncateBeforeLoad) {
                //delete data from table before loading csv
                con.createStatement().execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            }

            final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;
            Date date = null;
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                if (null != nextLine) {
                    int index = 1;
                    for (String string : nextLine) {
                        date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);
                        if (null != date) {
                            ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date
                                    .getTime()));
                        } else {
                            ps.setString(index++, string);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(count);
                    ps.addBatch();
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
                if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    System.out.println(count);
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }
            ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
            con.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(
                    "Error occured while loading data from file to database."
                            + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (null != ps)
                ps.close();
            if (null != con)
                con.close();

            csvReader.close();
        }
    }

    public char getSeprator() {
        return seprator;
    }

    public void setSeprator(char seprator) {
        this.seprator = seprator;
    }

}
```

` 
When executing it I am getting error as "No value specified for parameter 23".
My database table has 22 columns and the csv file also has 22 columns.So I am guessing that in the first row itself there is a text which has a comma in it and it is not able to parse it and hence it is assuming as 23 columns and not 22.
Can anyone help me in clarifying the problem and providing me solution.

Comment: > So I am guessing that in the first row itself there is a text which has a comma in it... Well, is there or is there not? I would assume you can check this. We certainly can't, and it is an important piece of information to this puzzle.

Comment: you might find useful [LOAD DATA INFILE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Yes there is comma in the first row itself.What I meant by saying in the post is that I am guessing that it is considering 23 columns because of this comma

Comment: Are your text fields in your csv file quoted? or the comma (that is not the delimiter) escaped? Did you generate the csv file or is it from another source?

Comment: The csv file is downloaded from net.When I open it then the text in the column where I assume the problem is coming(one which has comma as part of text) is surrounded by <p> </p>

Comment: Hmm damn, unfortunately that doesn't help as the CSVReader constructor I was going to suggest only takes a single char as a quote. You could still do this but means you would have to manipulate the file (or the strings in your nextLine array) and check for those tags replacing them (or appending) a quote character.

Comment: cant you use something like spring batch instead of developing your own code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the immediate issue is that you do not escape the column names while inserting them into your SQL statement. What you are creating is a statement of this form:

```
INSERT INTO sometable(key1,key2,key3) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

Now if you have a comma in a header row (let's say one key is "ke,y3" instead), even if it is read correctly by your CSV library, you will be creating something like this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable(key1,key2,ke,y3) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

Now you have a mismatch in the number of values and the number of columns. Note that this can also happen with some other characters: Maybe you have a question mark in one key that is interpreted as a parameter placeholder?

The solution: To save yourself some headache, avoid these characters in the keys if possible. I'm not sure how and if mysql will handle them properly, but if it does, you need to at least escape the column names before inserting them. I'm not sure how you would do that properly and safely (to prevent SQL injection), but since this is apparently a one-off tool, wrapping the column names in backticks like this should be good enough:

```
INSERT INTO sometable(`key1`,`key2`,`ke,y3`) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of comma in a CSV file.  One type of comma separates fields, the other type of comma is part of text and **always** occurs between quotes.  You need to parse commas outside quotes differently from commas inside quotes.  Your code does not appear to do this.  Perhaps something like:

```
repeat
  c <-read next character
  if (c == '"')
    parse quoted field  // May include commas.
  else
    parse non-quoted field // Will not include commas.
  endif
until file all read.
```

Using different methods to parse quoted and non-quoted fields makes it easy to treat the two types of comma correctly.

Comment: This is not the issue here. He is using a library for CSV reading already which properly handles this.

Comment: Yes I thought csvreader does handle it but it is still throwing the error.